# Why does not std::nullptr_t work with std::cout in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, ambiguous, nullptr

I learned about `std::nullptr_t` that is the type of the null pointer literal, `nullptr`.

Then I made small program :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::nullptr_t n1; 
    std::cout<<n1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `nullptr_t` is data type and `n1` is variable and I'm trying to print the value of variable. But, Compiler give an error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:6:11: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::nullptr_t')
  std::cout<<n1<<endl;
```

Why does not `std::nullptr_t`  work with `std::cout` in C++? What am I wrong here?

Comment: Just a guess, but since `std::nullptr_t` is the type of the null pointer literal `nullptr`, the value of `n1` is `nullptr`. So you're trying to output `nullptr` but `operator<<` is overloaded for several types of pointers, so the compiler doesn't know how to choose.

Comment: Besides, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @rhobincu If I write `int i`; and `cout<<i<<endl;` working fine, but `nullptr_t` why give an error?

Comment: `void f(long); void f(short);` Calling `f(0);` would also be ambiguous. Same reason here.

Comment: If you try and output an integer variable, the program will print the value of that variable. What do you expect to see when you print a nullptr_t variable?

Comment: @rhobincu I think print 0.

Comment: Following @rhobincu you can cast the n1 to a pointer type or integral type to output it.

Comment: But a nullptr_t variable can't hold an integer value, so it can't be 0.

Comment: More importantly, which actual problem needs addresses written to `std::cout`? I don't think we're helping you as much as we can if we merely consider this question the iceberg rather than the tip of the iceberg. You shouldn't want to or need to write addresses to `std::cout` any more than you should want to or need to read addresses from `std::cin`.

Answer (score 10):

`operator<<` for output streams has overloads for multiple different types of pointers, *but not `std::nullptr_t`* <sup>1</sup>. This means that the compiler cannot determine which overload to call, because *any* of the overloads accepting a pointer are equally good. (For example, it accepts `char const *` for C-style strings, and also `void const *`, which will output the raw pointer value.)

One option to fix this would be to define your own overload that forces the use of the `void const *` overload:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &s, std::nullptr_t) {
    return s << static_cast<void *>(nullptr);
}
```

Or have it do something else:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &s, std::nullptr_t) {
    return s << "nullptr";
}
```

---

Notes:

- <sup>1</sup> As pointed out in the comments, there is an overload accepting `std::nullptr_t` in C++17, so this will cease to be an issue if you are using a conforming C++17 implementation.
- `endl` needs `std::`-qualification -- but you should use `'\n'` here anyway.  (`std::endl` is only a good idea when you need the stream flushed.)

Comment: Note that this issue got resolved in C++17: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt
However, none of the compilers I tried seems to support it yet.

Comment: @Jodocus It's not a compiler issue, but a library one. libstdc++ and libc++ both don't implement it, yes.

Comment: overloading an operator outside of a type's namespace is bad, and in std is illegal.

Comment: @Yakk can you elaborate?

Comment: @fureeeish Overloading an operator of importance and distinction, outside or not in, the namespace in which a type (not to typecast) is defined, is a less than ideal (one could say bad) idea, due to ADL failure, while defining overloads within the namespace std is ill advised as it renders your program as formed as the action is advised.  Thus we fall upon the saying, one is damned if one does, so don't do it.  Had the type a template parameter from outside std, then your woes would be washed on the tide of no more troubles.  (That is as elaborate as I can write given character limit)

Comment: According to the standard (section 20.5.4.2.1 [namespace.std]): "The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified." So, adding an overload for `nullptr_t` is not permitted according to the standard. That being said, most compilers still let you get away with it, but just know that it could break at any time for any reason.

Comment: @callyalater Can't the operator be added to your program's namespace? I forget the visibility rules for free operators, but I thought the compiler will search the namespaces for the argument types as well as the namespaces you can access without explicit scope resolution.

Comment: Only if one of the inputs to the stream is a user defined type outside of the `std` namespace (for it to be legal). That said, most compilers will still let you do it because it is easier that way.

Comment: Just met it myself… turns out that it works on `clang` (C++17 mode), but fails on `gcc` (C++17 mode as well).