# Can std::cout print "NULL" instead of 0 when printing a null pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Can `std::cout` print "**NULL**" instead of **0** when printing a null pointer?? I can write a simple if statement like

```cpp
if(pointer == nullptr)
  std::cout << "NULL";
```

But can I get the same result without using an if statement?

Comment: What output are you talking about?

Comment: @JHBonarius Apparently OP wants `cout` to print null pointers as `"nullptr"`.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256697/why-does-not-stdnullptr-t-work-with-stdcout-in-c

Comment: My favorite is the overloaded stream insertion operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really escape using an if statement, but you can make it into a one-liner with the ternary operator:
`(p == NULL ? std::cout << "NULL" : std::cout << p);`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  void *p = NULL;
  (p == NULL ? std::cout << "NULL" : std::cout << p);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  p = new int;
  (p == NULL ? std::cout << "NULL" : std::cout << p);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/RecentWorrisomeKnowledge)

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of the ternary operator, `?`.

```cpp
pointer ? std::cout << pointer : std::cout << "NULL";
```

or with the gnu c++ compiler extension **IF** your pointer is a `char*`

```cpp
std::cout << (pointer ?: "NULL");
```

granted that the second way will not work on all compilers because it is not officially part of the language.

I do not believe that there is an equivalent to [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) for pointers.

[EDIT]

As pointed out by @seleciii44, in the stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256697/why-does-not-stdnullptr-t-work-with-stdcout-in-c), you can write your own overloaded stream insertion operator

```cpp
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &s, std::nullptr_t)
{
    return s << "nullptr";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if type of pointer is not `char *`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/IvWn3HRb4y7XvyCL

Comment: Thanks, fixed it so that it should work with non `char *` pointers

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 2 ways.

1) The clear way: use ternary operator (?:)

```
    cout<<((ptr)?"":"NULL\n");
```

2) The nasty way, if you really don't want to use any conditional statements.

```
    cout<<&("NULL"[4*(!!ptr)]);
```

**Why it works ?**

!!ptr will set the value of ptr to 0 or 1 based on its value.

If it is null cout will see the char* starting from 0 index and will print "NULL", otherwise
it will see it from index 4 and will print the terminating char.

This a very bad way as nullptr may be implementation defined and may be not portable.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't print the terminating char.  The terminating `\0` ends the loop, so no characters are printed.  Should be very portable, as all the operations are well defined.  But may be confusing, so deserves a comment if used in production code.

Comment: Could do it as `cout << &"\0NULL"<:!ptr:>;` to shock your coworkers.

Comment: Only problem is that it won't print the pointer if it is valid... Clever idea nonetheless